# Partial/near match for name and/or username in Active Directory / Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Our users sometimes gives us misspelled names/usernames and I would like to be able to search active directory for a near match, sorting by closest (any algorithm would be fine). 
For example, if I try

`Get-Aduser -Filter {GivenName -like "Jack"}`

I can find the user Jack, but not if I use "Jacck" or "ack"

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: If any of the below solutions work for you, please select an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, based on the great answers that I got (thanks @boxdog and @Palle Due) I am posting a more complete one.

Major source: https://github.com/gravejester/Communary.PASM - PowerShell Approximate String Matching. Great Module for this topic.

#### 1) FuzzyMatchScore function

source: https://github.com/gravejester/Communary.PASM/tree/master/Functions

```
# download functions to the temp folder
$urls = 
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gravejester/Communary.PASM/master/Functions/Get-CommonPrefix.ps1"    ,
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gravejester/Communary.PASM/master/Functions/Get-LevenshteinDistance.ps1" ,
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gravejester/Communary.PASM/master/Functions/Get-LongestCommonSubstring.ps1"  ,
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gravejester/Communary.PASM/master/Functions/Get-FuzzyMatchScore.ps1" 

$paths = $urls | %{$_.split("\/")|select -last 1| %{"$env:TEMP\$_"}}

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
for($i=0;$i -lt $urls.count;$i++){
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $urls[$i] -OutFile $paths[$i]
}

# concatenating the functions so we don't have to deal with source permissions
foreach($path in $paths){
cat $path | Add-Content "$env:TEMP\Fuzzy_score_functions.ps1"
}

# to save for later, open the temp folder with: Invoke-Item $env:TEMP 
# then copy "Fuzzy_score_functions.ps1" somewhere else

# source Fuzzy_score_functions.ps1
. "$env:TEMP\Fuzzy_score_functions.ps1"
```

Simple test:

```
Get-FuzzyMatchScore "a" "abc" # 98
```

Create a score function:

```
## start function
function get_score{
param($searchQuery,$searchData,$nlist,[switch]$levd)

if($nlist -eq $null){$nlist = 10}

$scores = foreach($string in $searchData){
    Try{
    if($levd){    
        $score = Get-LevenshteinDistance $searchQuery $string }
    else{
        $score = Get-FuzzyMatchScore -Search $searchQuery -String $string }
    Write-Output (,([PSCustomObject][Ordered] @{
                        Score = $score
                        Result = $string
                    }))
    $I = $searchData.indexof($string)/$searchData.count*100
    $I = [math]::Round($I)
    Write-Progress -Activity "Search in Progress" -Status "$I% Complete:" -PercentComplete $I
    }Catch{Continue}
}

if($levd) { $scores | Sort-Object Score,Result |select -First $nlist }
else {$scores | Sort-Object Score,Result -Descending |select -First $nlist }
} ## end function
```

Examples

```
get_score "Karolin" @("Kathrin","Jane","John","Cameron")

# check the difference between Fuzzy and LevenshteinDistance mode
$names = "Ferris","Cameron","Sloane","Jeanie","Edward","Tom","Katie","Grace"
"Fuzzy"; get_score "Cam" $names
"Levenshtein"; get_score "Cam" $names -levd
```

Test the performance on a big dataset

```
## donload baby-names

$url = "https://github.com/hadley/data-baby-names/raw/master/baby-names.csv"
$output = "$env:TEMP\baby-names.csv"
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
$babynames = import-csv "$env:TEMP\baby-names.csv"
$babynames.count # 258000 lines

$babynames[0..3] # year, name, percent, sex

$searchdata = $babynames.name[0..499]

$query = "Waren" # missing letter
"Fuzzy"; get_score $query $searchdata
"Levenshtein"; get_score $query $searchdata -levd

$query = "Jon" # missing letter
"Fuzzy"; get_score $query $searchdata
"Levenshtein"; get_score $query $searchdata -levd

$query = "Howie" # lookalike
"Fuzzy"; get_score $query $searchdata;
"Levenshtein"; get_score $query $searchdata -levd
```

Test

```
$query = "John"

$res = for($i=1;$i -le 10;$i++){
    $searchdata = $babynames.name[0..($i*100-1)]
    $meas = measure-command{$res = get_score $query $searchdata}
    write-host $i
    Write-Output (,([PSCustomObject][Ordered] @{
        N = $i*100
        MS = $meas.Milliseconds
        MS_per_line = [math]::Round($meas.Milliseconds/$searchdata.Count,2)
                    }))
}
$res

+------+-----+-------------+
| N    | MS  | MS_per_line |
| -    | --  | ----------- |
| 100  | 696 | 6.96        |
| 200  | 544 | 2.72        |
| 300  | 336 | 1.12        |
| 400  | 6   | 0.02        |
| 500  | 718 | 1.44        |
| 600  | 452 | 0.75        |
| 700  | 224 | 0.32        |
| 800  | 912 | 1.14        |
| 900  | 718 | 0.8         |
| 1000 | 417 | 0.42        |
+------+-----+-------------+
```

These times are quite crazy, if anyone understand why please comment on it.

#### 2) Generate a table of Names from Active Directory

The best way to do this depends on the organization of the AD. Here we have many OUs, but common users will be in Users and DisabledUsers. Also Domain and DC will be different (I'm changing ours here to `<domain>` and `<DC>`).

```
# One way to get a List of OUs
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -Properties CanonicalName | 
  Select-Object -Property CanonicalName
```

then you can use `Where-Object -FilterScript {}` to filter per OU

```
# example, saving on the temp folder
Get-ADUser -f * |
 Where-Object -FilterScript {
    ($_.DistinguishedName -match "CN=\w*,OU=DisabledUsers,DC=<domain>,DC=<DC>" -or
    $_.DistinguishedName -match "CN=\w*,OU=Users,DC=<domain>,DC=<DC>") -and
    $_.GivenName -ne $null #remove users without givenname, like test users
    } | 
    select @{n="Fullname";e={$_.GivenName+" "+$_.Surname}},
    GivenName,Surname,SamAccountName |
    Export-CSV -Path "$env:TEMP\all_Users.csv" -NoTypeInformation
# you can open the file to inspect 
Invoke-Item "$env:TEMP\all_Users.csv"
# import
$allusers = Import-Csv "$env:TEMP\all_Users.csv"
$allusers.Count # number of lines
```

Usage:

```
get_score "Jane Done" $allusers.fullname 15 # return the 15 first
get_score "jdoe" $allusers.samaccountname 15
```

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the two strings and make sure it's under a certain threshold (probably 1 or 2). There is a powershell example here:
[Levenshtein distance in powershell](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/102192/Levenshtein-Distance-in-Windows-PowerShell)

Examples:

- Jack and Jacck have an LD of 1.
- Jack and ack have an LD of 1.
- Palle and Havnefoged have an LD of 8.

Comment: Thanks! So I would build a table of names from AD, compute the LD distance on all, then sort based on the distance. Each LD calculation takes about 19ms using that example, so for 10000 words run time would be 3.16min. Any ideas on how to improve performance on this without going to another language?

Comment: @RBA: Maybe you can skip the rest of the calculation the minute you have a number larger than 2 on the "diagonal" (I know there is a name for it, I've just forgotten) in the matrix. Or you can implement a cmdlet in C# and have the benefit of compiled code.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question and answers. But a possible simpler solution is to search by more than one attribute as I would hope most people would spell one of their names properly :)

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {GivenName -like "FirstName" -or SurName -Like "SecondName"}
```

Comment: Nice lateral thinking :-)

Comment: I've tried that. Most of the time we don't have problems when they are giving their name, but name of others, like supervisors or colleagues, so typos and misspellings come in all directions. Another problem is that our AD is a mess and a lot of users have Surname and Givenname switched.

Comment: you can also add additional filters based on the OU the user is in, the groups he/she is a member of or any other attribute accessible in Active Directory. I know you specifically asked for an algorithm, I added my answer for anybody else that might find it useful or finds Palle Due's answer a bit daunting to implement.

Comment: With -like, you might as well use a wildcard `*`.

Answer (score 1):

The [Soundex](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) algorithm is designed for just this situation.  Here is some PowerShell code that might help:

[Get-Soundex.ps1](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Communary.PASM/1.0.41/Content/Functions%5CGet-Soundex.ps1)

Comment: I thought of that as well, but given @RBA's examples I went for Levenshtein. Soundex("Jack") is J000, Soundex("ack") is A200. That's pretty far apart. It also seems he is more after misspellings than words sounding alike.

Comment: I guess it depends on if most misspellings are unintended typos or actual attempts at a name the user doesn’t know how to spell. Soundex is more suited to the latter, where there is likely to be reasonable similarity.  Also, another possible advantage that spring to mind (though I haven’t tried it) is that the encoding could be calculated in advance and added as a property of the user in AD, which will make searching in AD more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This somewhat works with ambiguous name resolution of various properties, but not the "Jacck" misspelling.  I get all five results.

```
get-aduser -filter 'anr -eq "ack"' -ResultSetSize 5
```